# set android.intent.category.default to custom app after factory reset

Tags: android-intent, settings, android-source

scenario:
pre-note: we want to offer an customized android build to customers like the known mobilephone or tablet manufactures do.

E.g. android sys provides an email app which is flagged with intent-filter category tag "android.intent.category.default" in it's AndroidManifest.xml.
Believe us developed another much cooler, mind blowing ;-) email app and also declared the "android.intent.category.default" intent.filter category in the Manifest.
Of course we set our app as default when it comes to the selection screen which app to always use. Of course the user will never clear defaults in app settings and always use the best email app on planet :-).

User decided to execute a full factory device reset. Next time a user is starting the email app he/she will end up in getting the "Selection overlay" to select the email app to proceed with.

How to omit this selection screen by setting the email app as default on device startup?
Where does android store such previous selected default app settings?

One possible way is to remove the default category intent-filter from androids default email apps Manifest. We don't want to do this.

Comment: I know that ResolverActivity and PackageManager "addPreferredActivity" are part of the game.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need this option:

android:priority="2"

```
<intent-filter android:priority="2">
    <action android:name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

You might find it in the "start up wizard" like applications.
For example, the one in GoogleServiceFramework.apk come along with GMS packages. You can see that this intent filter makes the wizard application dominate the home screen application(launcher) and got started before home screen after factory reset. User does not need to select which action shall be taken for the intent "home". And after the wizard finishes, it will disable itself, and then home screen got displayed.

Please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority

The priority that should be given to the parent component with regard to handling intents of the type described by the filter. This attribute has meaning for both activities and broadcast receivers:
It provides information about how able an activity is to respond to an intent that matches the filter, relative to other activities that could also respond to the intent. When an intent could be handled by multiple activities with different priorities, Android will consider only those with higher priority values as potential targets for the intent.
It controls the order in which broadcast receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with higher priority values are called before those with lower values. (The order applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages.)
Use this attribute only if you really need to impose a specific order in which the broadcasts are received, or want to force Android to prefer one activity over others.

The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.

Comment: Thanks Robin for the priority hint.

Comment: I played around with some apps and homescreen regarding this "priority" attribute to see what it effects.
Unfortunately I faced two problems with e.g. homescreen apps.
1st: in file: /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml - see belows snippet, there is no such preferred-activities entry anymore.

Comment: <preferred-activities>
<item name="com.example.homescreen/.HomescreenActivity"match="100000" set="2">
<set name="com.example.homescreen/.HomescreenActivity" />
<set name="com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher" />
<filter>
<action name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<cat name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<cat name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</filter>
</item>
</preferred-activities>

Comment: above code snippet doesn't appear anymore in package-restrictions.xml file.
2nd: somehow the home button press has no effect anymore if two homescreens exist. 
If you are in Launcher2 homescreen and press "Home" btn it will not go back to com.example.homescreen.HomescreenActivity 
and also onPause() Method of Launcher2 is not called. I expected due to priority property the new app/homescreen opens.

Comment: this is my test apps manifest snippet:<activity
            android:name="com.example.homescreen.HomescreenActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="2" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: I think it should work before you have used any one of them. That is to say, you can test with 2 home screen apks, one have default priority and one has high priority. Both installed in system/app and start from "factory reset"

Comment: you are right, it works. Example home screen (with priority attribute = 2) starts without getting the selection overlay. Fine so far. But for me, if example home screen sends and intent to open Laucnher2, there you press "Home" btn, nothing will happen. I put a log to onPause() method in launcher2 but no feedback. Same if I open any app from example home screen. Being in this app I press "Home" btn OS neither switches to example home screen nor to launcher2. Any idea?

Comment: I am sorry I did not quite understand your last comment, could you explain again? Please modify your question and put more information there. It has better format in the main question section.

Comment: added modified question, findings and problems in answer2, see above block

Answer (score 0):

let me start again.... I played arround a bit with that priority property.

I created an new Homescreen App having the following activity snippet in the manifest:

```
<activity 
 android:name="com.example.homescreen.HomescreenActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
 android:screenOrientation="landscape" > 
 <intent-filter android:priority="2" >
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> 
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Androids Launcher2 has the same <intent-filter> part except the "priority attribute".

Scenario 1:
I set new home screen as default app for home screens. Then I make a full factory reset to check if I have to set default home screen again afer startup.
I have a single btn in my UI sending an intent to start Launcher2. After Android's Launcher2 started successfully I pressed "Home" btn (hardware key). Or starting an app from Launcher2's app grid and then pressing the "Home" btn.
Result: "Home" has no effect, app is not exited neither Launcher2 returns to new home screen app.

Scenario 2:
I don't use the priority attribute in my new home screen app but initially set this App as default Launcher when Android detects a new Homescreen was added/downloaded.
Here, if I check filesystem: **/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml**, this xml has the following tag filled with my new home screen app.

```
<preferred-activities>
  <item name="com.example.homescreen/.HomescreenActivity" match="100000" set="2">
    <set name="com.example.homescreen/.HomescreenActivity" />
    <set name="com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher" />
    <filter>
      <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <cat name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
      <cat name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </filter>
  </item>
</preferred-activities>
```

If I now continue doing the same steps as before, executing factory reset, I need to set the default home screen again. But if I have done so and press the "Home" btn, I will always return to my new home screen app.
I also wondered why in Scenario 1, I only have a empty

```
<preferred-activities/>
```

tag in this package-restrictions file. I thought this priority will maybe add me such entry automatically.
**So what I want to archieve is that I make a full reset and do not have to choose my default home screen app next time.
Same thing for other apps not being a home screen launcher app.**

Comment: Thanks for elaborating the details. I think the 'priority' is some different mechanism than the 'preferred-activities'. I haven't got the time check the whole story from the source code. But could you post the logcat printings to see if there is some output when you press the home button in scenario ONE.

Answer (score 0):

logcat output:
1) new home screen is active, I press button to open Launcher2 (by intent), Launcher2 opens:

```
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(  129): getDeviceForStrategy() unknown strategy: 6
D/dalvikvm( 1436): GC_CONCURRENT freed 180K, 6% free 5535K/5868K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 30ms
D/dalvikvm( 1436): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 25ms
D/dalvikvm( 1436): GC_CONCURRENT freed 295K, 8% free 5722K/6168K, paused 5ms+6ms, total 39ms
D/libEGL  ( 1436): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
D/libEGL  ( 1436): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
D/libEGL  ( 1436): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
D/OpenGLRenderer( 1436): Enabling debug mode 0
D/dalvikvm( 1436): GC_CONCURRENT freed 208K, 6% free 5967K/6324K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 28ms
I/ActivityManager(  486): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +653ms
D/dalvikvm( 1436): GC_CONCURRENT freed 247K, 8% free 6145K/6612K, paused 6ms+2ms, total 36ms
D/dalvikvm( 1436): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
D/dalvikvm( 1436): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 250K, 8% free 6254K/6780K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1436): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.235MB for 313616-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1436): GC_CONCURRENT freed 147K, 7% free 6696K/7160K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 27ms
```

2) I press "Home" btn when Launcher2 or any other app is active:

```
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(  129): getDeviceForStrategy() unknown strategy: 6
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(  129): getDeviceForStrategy() unknown strategy: 6
```

Comment: I've added a Log.i("#####", "#### Launcher2 onPause() called"); msg in Launcher2's onPause() method which doesn't show in logcat output as you can see above. But for Scenario 2 with a default entry in package-restrictions.xml I will see my Log msg so in that case onPause of Launcher2 is really called.